# memory error while getting the combinations of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create combination of 34 items. when I limit max combinations to 10, there are no problems. however when I try to get the combination of more, I am having memory error. (MemoryError: Unable to allocate X GiB for an array with shape (X, Y) and data type float64) I am already using 64bit python, what would help with the iteration of these?

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

header = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134]
combs= []
max_combinations = 20

for i in range(1, len(header)+1):
        if i < max_combinations:
            print (i)
            els = [list(x) for x in it.combinations(header, i)]
            combs.extend(els)
            
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: combs})
```

Comment: Buy more RAM for your computer...

Comment: Your numbers are all integers. Where does `float64` come from?

Comment: One of the reasons that `combinations` creates a lazy iterator is that the number of combinations explodes as `i` gets bigger. You can't realistically store all of the in memory at once, but you can often process and discard them one at a time.

Comment: is there any other way to do the combination so it is not stored in the memory but writes to hard drive instead?

Comment: If you make `combs` a generator do you get any farther? `combs = (list(x) for i in range(1, len(header)+1) if i < max_combinations for x in it.combinations(header, i))`

Comment: Is the result you seek something in the order of 38 choose 19 lists plus 38 choose 18 lists plus ... That will be a "big number"

Answer (score 0):

You are really just running out of RAM. Not much you can do there.

A list by itself takes 56 B. Each 64-bit int in the list takes 8 B more.

I don't know the size of your array but say...
If your list of lists is say 100,000 x 100,000
This will take about:

One list is 100000 x 8 + 56 = 805,600 B

1000 lists is then: 100000 x 805.6 kB = 80,560 MB

In a list = 80,560.000056 MB ~ 80G

If you have the ability to specify the datatype so you are using the minimum number of bits possible this could reduce your RAM usage slightly.

See the comment by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) below for the memory required by a Python `int`.

Comment: It's worse than that. An `int` in Python takes at least 24 bytes, even for small integers, because the actual bits that specify the magnitude is only a part of the object. These are arbitrary precision integers, not fixed-length machine integers.

Comment: Ah good to know thanks

Comment: Most of the memory is being used up before the attempt to create the dataframe is even made.